# How to add support for South Korea to jBilling

Tags: jbilling

How can I add support for another region or language or currency to [jBilling](https://github.com/WebDataConsulting/billing/tree/master)

Comment: Well, solved this [here](https://github.com/WebDataConsulting/billing/wiki/How-to-Translate-jBilling-4.x-to-a-new-language)

Answer (score 0):

when you create admin entry or Entity signup by hiting ( `http://<host>:<port>/jbilling/signup` ). there you get get all details. put language, country and currency for South Korea.
hope this will help you